# How to define a default button in MS VB Express 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to define a default button in MS VB Express 2010.

Anything in DESIGN or code view is fine

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net MVC? Silverlight?

Comment: All I know is that I am using MS Visual Basic Express 2010 and My project is a Windows Form Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the AcceptButton property in the form's Properties window.

Comment: See the [MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) for more information on AcceptButton